# Get the name of the "method argument" in aspect ? (AspectJ)

Tags: aspectj, aspect, spring-aspects

How can I get  the name of argument in aspect, for example if my method is test(Sample sampleDto), I need know the name of sampleDto in my aspect. How get it from ProceedingJoinPoint ?
I try this, but I get null.

```
String[] argumentsName = ((MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this and it worked

```
Reporter.log(gson.toJson(((MethodSignature) jp.getSignature()).getParameterNames()), true);
Reporter.log(gson.toJson(jp.getArgs()), true);
```

Output

```
[
  "externalOrderId",
  "tenderDto",
  "checksum",
  "cookieToken"
]
[
  "C605600399",
  {
    "number": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expiration": "XXXXXX",
    "pin": "XXX",
    "type": "CREDITCARD"
  },
  1514412484857,
  "50113963101%2CP08rS1wzJiYqQEA3ODEkQVZWLy8sTksmMyNPJH4mXj0jQi1KOThfTld%2BQCQh"
]
```